# Instance caching in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, weak-references

I want to cache the instances of a certain class. The class keeps a dictionary of all its instances and when somebody requests a new instance, the class tries to satisfy the request from the cache first. There is a small problem with memory management though: The dictionary cache retains the inserted objects, so that they never get deallocated. I do want them to get deallocated, so that I had to overload the `release` method and when the retain count drops to one, I can remove the instance from cache and let it get deallocated.

This works, but I am not comfortable mucking around the `release` method and find the solution overly complicated. I thought I could use some hashing class that does not retain the objects it stores. Is there such? The idea is that when the last user of a certain instance releases it, the instance would automatically disappear from the cache.

[NSHashTable](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) seems to be what I am looking for, but the documentation talks about “supporting weak relationships in a garbage-collected environment.” Does it also work without garbage collection?

---

*Clarification:* I cannot afford to keep the instances in memory unless somebody really needs them, that is why I want to purge the instance from the cache when the last “real” user releases it.

---

*Better solution:* This was on the iPhone, I wanted to cache some textures and on the other hand I wanted to free them from memory as soon as the last real holder released them. The easier way to code this is through another class (let’s call it `TextureManager`). This class manages the texture instances and caches them, so that subsequent calls for texture with the same name are served from the cache. There is no need to purge the cache immediately as the last user releases the texture. We can simply keep the texture cached in memory and when the device gets short on memory, we receive the low memory warning and can purge the cache. This is a better solution, because the caching stuff does not pollute the `Texture` class, we do not have to mess with `release` and there is even a higher chance for cache hits. The `TextureManager` can be abstracted into a `ResourceManager`, so that it can cache other data, not only textures.

Comment: Why do you want to release objects that the dictionary is retaining? If you want the dictionary to drop its reference, you should unset the key.

Comment: I want the dictionary to drop its reference automatically when there is nobody else retaining the object. I’ve edited the question, hope it’s clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use an NSHashTable to build what is essentially a non-retaining dictionary. Alternatively, you can call CFDictionaryCreate with NULL for release and retain callbacks. You can then simply typecast the result to a NSDictionary thanks to tollfree bridging, and use it just like a normal NSDictionary except for not fiddling with retain counts.

If you do this the dictionary will not automatically zero the reference, you will need to make sure to remove it when you dealloc an instance.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a zeroing weak reference (it's not a "Graal of cache managing algorithms", it's a well known pattern). The problem is that Objective C provides you with zeroing weak references only when running with garbage collection, not in manual memory managed programs. And the iPhone does not provide garbage collection (yet).

All the answers so far seem to point you to half-solutions.

Using a non-reataining reference is not sufficient because you will need to zero it out (or remove the entry from the dictionary) when the referenced object is deallocated. However this must be done BEFORE the -dealloc method of that object is called otherwise the very existence of the cache expose you to the risk that the object is resurrected. The way to do this is to dynamically subclass the object when you create the weak reference and, in the dynamically created subclass, override -release to use a lock and -dealloc to zero out the weak reference(s).

This works in general but it fails miserably for toll-free bridged Core Foundation objects. Unfortunately the only solution, if you need to to extend the technique to toll-free bridged objects, requires some hacking and undocumented stuff (see [here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-30-zeroing-weak-references-to-corefoundation-objects.html) for code and explanations) and is therefore not usable for iOS or programs that you want to sell on the Mac App Store.

If you need to sell on the Apple stores and must therefore avoid undocumented stuff, your best alternative is to implement locked access to a retaining cache and then scavenge it for references with a current -retainCount value of 1 when you want to release memory. As long as all accesses to the cache are done with the lock held, if you observe a count of 1 while holding the lock you know that there's no-one that can resurrect the object if you remove it from the cache (and therefore release it) before relinquishing the lock.

For iOS you can use UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification to trigger the scavenging. On the mac you need to implement your own logic: maybe just a periodical check or even simply a periodical scavenging (both solutions would also work on iOS).

Answer (score 2):

I've just implemented this kind of thing by using an NSMutableDictionary and registering for UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification. On a memory warning I remove anything from the dictionary with a retainCount of 1...

Comment: You shouldn't call or use retainCount in production code. http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:] to wrap the instance in an NSValue and put that in the dictionary.  In the instance dealloc method, remove the corresponding entry from the dictionary. No messing with retain.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to implement the Graal of cache managing algorithms: drop items that will no longer be used.

You may want to consider other criteria, such as dropping the least recently requested items.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I would approach this is to maintain a separate count or a flag somewhere to indicate if the object in the cache is being used or not. You could then check this when you're done with an object, or just run a check every n seconds to see if it needs to be released or not.

I would avoid any solution involving releasing the object before removing it from the dictionary (using NSValue's `valueWithNonretainedObject:` would be another way to accomplish this). It would just cause you problems in the long run.